# having issues downloading xls file using procmail

Tags: procmail

Any ideas why my xls attachment files aren't being downloaded? thanks This is a perl wrapper creating the procmailrc file for me.

```
    my $procmailrc =<<EOL;
MAILDIR=$workDir
VERBOSE=on
LOGFILE=$workDir/procmail.log
:0 B
* ^Content-Type.*application.*name=.*\.(xls|rtf)
{
   MAILDIR
}
:0
mail/
EOL
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated recipe is syntactically correct, but semantically bogus; this is almost certainly not what you want. The `MAILDIR` between the braces is equivalent to `MAILDIR=''` i.e. you are setting the `MAILDIR` variable's value to nothing.  This causes the matching messages to be delivered to a different directory than your other messages, most likely a place you need to dig out from the log files so you can restore the misplaced messages.  Perhaps you do not have write access to the directory where you end up trying to deliver those messages, which will most likely cause the calling process to bounce them back to the sender.

Anyway, since you have a log file, please post a pertinent snippet (three-four lines should be all we need) if you still cannot figure this out.